# How did Batman know Zatanna wiped his memory?

Tags: dc, batman, justice-league

In 'Identity Crisis' (Jun-Dec 2004), we learn that Zatanna wiped Batman's memory a while ago.

In 'OMAC Project' (Jun-Nov 2005), we learn that Batman knew what happened and has a satellite set up to monitor the JLA to prevent further incidents like these.

However, it isn't clear how Batman knew this. I know it's never mentioned in the 'Batman' issues of the time (War Games/Under the Hood/War Crimes).

So, my question is: is it ever made clear how Batman came to know this? Did anyone present at the time tell him? Did Wally? Did Batman deduce it for himself?

If there is indeed a canon explanation, please tell me which issues to read to find it.

Comment: I'll bet he used something on his utility belt to do it.

Comment: @Broklynite: Haha. Or simply... BECAUSE HE's _BATMAN_

Comment: You know that's what it'll boil down to no matter the answer, right?

Answer (score 7):

It's never explicitly stated so far as I know, but Batman's whole thing is catching onto things that don't seem right and putting together the pieces to figure them out so it wouldn't be at all surpising that is what happened, but there are 2 other possibilities...

1. Batman records everything. His costume has sensors of all sort on it and it is constantly streaming to the batcave mainframe which he then reviews for figuring out what he did wrong during his fights. This is again one of those things that aren't really explicitly stated, but something you should pick up on with what he does in passing. The closest I can remember to it being explicitly stated is one time he had Oracle dowload video from his cowl camera to do something with.
2. Batman has fought Ivy, Scarecrow, Madhatter, and a number of others whose abilities are to brainwash you in one form or another. He even has a "back up" personality called the Batman of Zur-En-Arrh. So it is likely that when Zatanna wiped "his" memory, she only wiped one of Batman's personality's memories and not all of theirs. Basically, this boils down to Shadow Clone logic. You can do something to 1 personality and it just gets dropped out of existence while the original is perfectly fine and is producing another personality or already has one to take over from the previous one.

Comment: I like your first reason. Remember when he was reviewing Red Hood's moves in the batcave? Can't remember if that was shown in the comics, but it's definitely a big part of the animated adaptation.